# On opening the jar file it shows JCo library is not found

Tags: configuration, side-by-side

[image]

The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are lacking the Visual Studio 2005 C/C++ runtime libraries (Version 8.0) to be installed on the system. You need to install the appropriate [vcredist_x64.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18471) package which can be downloaded from Microsoft.